# VBA count and print every cell address when a duplicate value is found

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to count the number of cells where a duplicate value is found
 and then print them in a message box.
At the moment my code successfully finds the values but only print the cell with the second duplicate value and not all the cells with the same value . It must be something like this:

The id "wrong id" is used multiple times  ("ids") .
*ids of all cells, separated with comma. In this example “A6, A7” .Here is my code:

```
Sub sbFindDuplicatesInColumn()

Dim cell As Range
Dim mess As String
Dim rngcheck As Range
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim C As Range
Dim objDic
Dim strMsg As String

Set objDic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
Set rng1 = Range([a1], Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp))
For Each C In rng1

    If Len(C.Value) > 0 Then
        If Not objDic.exists(C.Value) Then
            objDic.Add C.Value, 1
        Else
            strMsg = strMsg & "The id" & C.Value & " is used multiple times " & C.Address(0, 0) & vbNewLine
        End If
    End If
Next
    If Len(strMsg) > 0 Then MsgBox strMsg
End Sub
```

Comment: So just to be clear, you want a single message box to say "The ID x is used multiple times at [Location 1], [Location 2], [Location 3], [Location 4], etc...", correct?

Comment: That `s right-to show all found cells

Comment: Why not use COUNTIF?

Comment: Because I want to do it as a macro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, say your list is

```
1
2
3
1
5
2
```

Your expected output is:

```
The id '1' is used multiple times: A1, A4
The id '2' is used multiple times: A2, A6
```

But your actual output is

```
The id '1' is used multiple times: A4
The id '2' is used multiple times: A6
```

This is because you don't store the first encounter of the index value, only **that** you encounter it.

Try something like this:

```
For Each C In rng1   
    If Len(C.Value) > 0 Then
        If Not objDic.exists(C.Value) Then
            objDic.Add C.Value, CStr(C.Address)
        Else
            objDic(C.Value) = objDic(C.Value) & ", " & CStr(C.Address)
        End If
    End If
Next

Dim comma As String, strMsg As String
strMsg = ""
For Each i In objDic.Keys
    pcs = Split(objDic(i), ",")
    If Ubound(pcs) > 1 Then
        strMsg = strMsg & "The id" & i & " is used multiple times "
        comma = ""
        For Each p In pcs
            strMsg = strMsg & comma & p
            comma = ", "
        Next
        strMsg = strMsg & vbNewLine
    End If
Next
If Len(strMsg) > 0 Then MsgBox strMsg
```

Comment: Here I received type mismatch `If Len(pcs) > 1 Then`

Comment: and here I think it must be `For Each i "not k" In objDic.Keys`

Comment: But it works in printing all of the cells for every value :D

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this, calling `SetUpDictionary` first, then using the `CheckDupe` function to check

```
Private dDupeChecker As Scripting.Dictionary

Function CheckDupe(rCheck As Excel.Range) As String
    If dDupeChecker.Exists(CStr(rCheck.Value)) Then
        CheckDupe = dDupeChecker(CStr(rCheck.Value))
    Else
        CheckDupe = "Ok, not a duplicate"
    End If
End Function

Sub SetUpDictionary()

Dim rFindOn As Excel.Range
Dim rLookAt As Excel.Range

Set dDupeChecker = New Scripting.Dictionary

Set rFindOn = Range("a1:a10")

For Each rLookAt In rFindOn.Cells
    If dDupeChecker.Exists(CStr(rLookAt.Value)) Then
        dDupeChecker(CStr(rLookAt.Value)) = dDupeChecker(CStr(rLookAt.Value)) & "," & rLookAt.Address
    Else
        dDupeChecker.Add CStr(rLookAt.Value), rLookAt.Address
    End If
Next rLookAt

End Sub
```

Comment: A made a msgbx: `MsgBox dDupeChecker(CStr(rLookAt.Value)) & "," & rLookAt.Address` but it shows the second duplicate twice

Comment: Yes, cause you've added it rlookat.address, you don't need to, it's stored in the dictionary